# Pseudo classes in styled-system?

Tags: reactjs, styled-system

Styled-system is a pretty popular styling framework. But nowhere in the docs they mention how to apply pseudo classes like `:hover`.

How would I style a simple button with a hover effect?

```js
<Button _hover={{}} />
```

Comment: I had never heard of `styled-system` but with a quick search it seems to be an abandoned project, if you're implementing something new I'd definitely look for a different framework.

Comment: yes and no, e.g. it's the foundation for styling libraries like chakra ui and some companies (mine) are still using it in prod.

Comment: Abandoned but mature enough